# History for ManyToMany tables not being tracked with django-simple-history

Tags: django, django-simple-history

I have this model:

```
class UserExtendProduct(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

Django created this table to manage this:

```
mysql> desc userextendproduct_products;
+----------------------+------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                   | int  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| userextendproduct_id | int  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| product_id           | int  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I created this model to represent that table:

```
class UserExtendProductProducts(models.Model):
    userextendproduct = models.ForeignKey(UserExtendProduct, models.DO_NOTHING)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, models.DO_NOTHING)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'userextendproduct_products'
        unique_together = ('userextendproduct', 'product')
```

When userextendproduct_products is updated I would expect historicaluserextendproductproducts to track that update, but it does not.

But here is something odd:I have 2 M2M relations and one is tracking history and one is not. For the one that is working the M2M table is `userinfo_institution` and the history table is `historicaluserinfo_institution`. The one that doesn't work (detailed above) the M2M table is `userextendproduct_products` and the history table is `historicaluserextendproductproducts` - note the missing underscore.

I have seen some posts here and also on the project's github page that talk about support for this being added. Is there something I am missing to get this working?

Comment: Well it is unmanaged, so that means you say you don't want Django to create tables...

Comment: The table does exist. Django created the table to manage the M2M relationship. I created the model so I could use django-simple-history,

Comment: yes, it exists by the m2m relation, it is not created by a model with a `HistoricalRecords` manager.

Comment: I just realized I had copy/pasted some incorrect details. I just updated the post above.

Comment: To summarize, ! have 2 M2M relations, and one tracks history and one does not. The difference is that for the one that works the history table matches the name of the underlying table (with historical prepended). For the one that does not work the history table has a different name form the underlying table - it's missing an underscore.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue. I had to add

```
history = HistoricalRecords(m2m_fields=[products])
```

Not sure where that is documented.